# How do you stop an onchange function from happening?

Tags: jquery, click, onchange

I am working on A Business Catalyst website that uses the eCommerce module.

One of my bugbears with this module is that after you select a zip/post code for delivery it gives you a radio button option for the cost but does not select it.

I find that a lot of people do not notice this, click the checkout button and cannot work out why an alert box appears.

I am trying to fix this by adding an apply button next to the zip/post code box that checks the radio box for them.

However, as there is some code that runs as soon as this field is changed as per below I need to click the apply button twice for my code to run.

Is there some way I can stop the onchange function from running and call it from my code, or is there a better option.

```
<input onchange="RetrieveShippingCosts(717471,267998);return false;" class="discountcodeInput" name="shippingPostcode" id="shippingPostcode" value="5008">

$( document ).ready(function() {            
    $("#shippingPostcode").after("<button class='btn' id='selectShipping'>Apply</button>");
    $(document).on("click", "#selectShipping", function () {
        $("#shippingCalc input").prop("checked", true);  
    }); 
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with:

```
$('#selectShipping').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
   //other codes....
});
```